# Out of memory error while running spark submit

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hive, bigdata

I am trying to load a 60gb table data onto a spark python dataframe and then write that into a hive table.

I have set driver memory, executor memory, max result size sufficiently to handle the data. But i am getting error when i run through spark submit with all the above said configs mentioned in command line.

Note: Through spark python shell (by specifying driver & executor memory while launching the shell), i am able to populate the target hive table.

Any thoughts??

Answer (score 0):

Try using syntax:

`./spark-submit --conf ...`

For the memory-related configuration. What I suspect you're doing is - you are setting them, while initializing `SparkSession` - which becomes irrelevant, since kernel is already started by then. Same parameters, as you set for running shell will do.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html